# Correct way to convert bytes to megabytes or gigabyte

Tags: memory

My macbook has 16GB RAM, but when I check my computer's total bytes with NodeJS or Go it reports `17179869184` bytes.

If I look at Google's calculator (e.g. do a google search "convert bytes to gb") it says:

- For GB divide bytes by 1e+9
- For MB divide bytes by 1e+6

The Google search calculators therefore give `17.179869184 GB` and `17179.869184 MB`.

However I've also seen the formula as:

- For GB divide bytes by 1024 / 1024 / 1024
- For MB divide bytes by 1024 / 1024

Which results in `16384 MB` and exactly `16GB`.

Which calculation is correct? Is my macbook 16GB or 17GB? Thanks.

Comment: Your MacBook has 16GB of RAM. Binary prefix was created to remove confusion. Gibibyte is the correct term in SI system. In computer world this is still called Gigabyte.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40949135/gigabyte-or-gibibyte-1000-or-1024

Comment: Ah of course! Thought it would be something simple. Thanks & feel free to answer or close as dupe I lack the power